# Enable grouping on protected sheet in Excel Online

Tags: excel, office365, office-js

Is there a way to enable grouping/ungrouping on a protected sheet in Excel Online, using the Excel Javascript APIs or otherwise? On Excel desktop the suggested way seems to be using the [EnableOutlining](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.enableoutlining.aspx) property which isn't saved with the worksheet.

The docs for the Javascript API don't have EnableOutlining as one of the properties we can set.

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheetprotectionoptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property is not yet supported. It is on our roadmap and will be part of the future API release. Don't have a date yet. Will update once we know. Thanks..